# How do I set REPORT_MAX_COUNT in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

We are having issues where our reports contain more rows than Excel can handle. I understand that if I set this I can set a limit on what is returned.

But I can't find a way to actually set it.

Comment: You can try to use [*net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.max.rows.per.sheet*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.max.rows.per.sheet) property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REPORT_MAX_COUNT is simply a parameter. How do you generate the report? From Java directly?
Have a look at the jasperreports ultimate guide (http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation?version=7114). It has a section on the REPORT_MAX_COUNT parameter.

I also recommend to have a look at ReportServer (http://reportserver.datenwerke.net/). It is an open source reporting plattform that supports JasperReports (as well as, Eclipse Birt) and comes with a very good integration of Excel.